# Design-wise, what would be the best way to design a UIPageViewController layout for reuse multiple times?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I'm using `UIPageViewController` in order to create a paging, zooming photo gallery akin to Photos.app.

Each `UIViewController` within the `UIPageViewController` will have a similar layout, consisting of a `UIImageView` for displaying the image and a `UILabel` for displaying a caption for the image.

This will be used multiple times for displaying different user galleries (think of a Flickr app where the user can tap to view a certain gallery/album).

How would I best go about designing this so I could reuse it easily, and with an object-oriented style design?

In code somehow? Do I subclass something (before iOS 6 you weren't allowed to subclass `UIPageViewController`, so what if that was still the case)? Is it possible to design it in something like a storyboard and then reuse that "template" in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need multiple UIPageViewControllers, just set up one with the layout you want and use it whenever you need a PageViewController.

Here is a tutorial that helped me understand how they work: http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/

Comment: I never said I need multiple, I said UIPageViewController *uses* multiple UIViewControllers, which is true. I know I only need one UIPageViewController in order to display a gallery, but I need to display multiple galleries so more than one UIPageViewController will be created, and I want the code to be reusable.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand what you're trying to do now. You want to have multiple UIPageViewControllers within one view all using the same template?

Comment: Not necessarily within one view, but separate view controllers will be able to open photo galleries, and I want to easily be able to instantiate a custom one.